# Payment intent is null on subscription with meter based pricing

Tags: stripe-payments

I am creating subscription using meter based pricing in stripe

```
      const stripeRequest: Stripe.SubscriptionCreateParams = {
        customer: customerId,
        items: [
          {
            price: xxxxxx
          },
        ],
        payment_settings: {
          payment_method_types: ["card"],
          save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription",
        },

        expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
      };

      const stripeSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create(
        stripeRequest,
      );
```

stripeSubscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent is coming as null

Answer (score 2):

For metered subscriptions, the customer is billed at the end of the billing period. So when you create a new metered subscription, an invoice is immediately created with a $0 amount. And since there's nothing to pay, it's expected that the invoice will have no PaymentIntent.

However the subscription object will contain a [`pending_setup_intent`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object?lang=node#subscription_object-pending_setup_intent) property. You could use the `client_secret` of this SetupIntent to collect a payment method on the frontend.